# Masking Account number to View only last 4 digits in DevExpress GridViewDataColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I need  to add a  Mask/DisplayFormatString  to view only  last 4  digits in DevExpress GridViewDataColumn.  As an example  if  the  real account number  is  `123456789`.  Then it  should  display as `*****6789`.
Can  you please  help me with this.

```
<dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Bank Account Number" FieldName="BankAccountNumber"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such native display format feature in `ASPxGridView` which obscures a string partially for certain first characters (a password mask is available but obscures all characters), however you can handle `ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText` event to produce custom masking with this workaround:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    // check column name first
    if (e.Column.FieldName != "BankAccountNumber")
        return;

    // get column values for BankAccountNumber
    string value = e.Value.ToString();

    // set asterisk to hide first n - 4 digits
    string asterisks = new string('*', value.Length - 4);

    // pick last 4 digits for showing
    string last = value.Substring(value.Length - 4, 4);

    // combine both asterisk mask and last digits
    string result = asterisks + last;

    // display as column text
    e.DisplayText = result;
}
```

**Side Note:** As the reference stated, *the text provided via this event will be used when the `ASPxGridView` is printed or exported*, probably you need separate `ASPxGridView` instance for export in multiple formats or printing.

Masking core example: [Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/updRsh)

Reference: [ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.CustomColumnDisplayText.event)

Related issue:

[ASPxGridView - How to use the CustomColumnDisplayText event handler](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q487306/aspxgridview-how-to-use-the-customcolumndisplaytext-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

Masking in for only input form, maybe you can use substring in serverside if you want view only 4 digit

Source :
https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/Features/MaskedInput.aspx